# downloading tensor flow on mac v10.13.4 with Virtualenv

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, virtualenv, errno

from the site tensorflow provides "[Installing TensorFlow on macOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac)" but after running the following command:

```
$ pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

I get the following message:

```
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached virtualenv-15.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Found existing installation: virtualenv 15.1.0
    Uninstalling virtualenv-15.1.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst' -> '/var/folders/dm/z1ygt5z102xg25tccf47jnw80000gn/T/pip-j5jm_3mq-uninstall/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 559, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv-15.1.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

Ive already downloaded python 3.6 from anaconda. im just not very good with terminal or understand any issue with the path.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `sudo` prefix to your installation command.

So:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```